# Spray JSON can't serialise case class

Tags: json, scala, spray

I am attempting to convert the following case class to/from JSON using Spray:

```
case class Interval(lower: Int, upper: Int)
```

This is achieved via:

```
implicit val intervalFormat = jsonFormat2(Interval)
```

This compiles, but gives the runtime error:

> Cannot automatically determine case class field names and order for 'Interval', please use the 'jsonFormat' overload with explicit field name specification

A search on this error suggests that it typically arises when subclasses declare additional fields, which is not the case here.

Am I mistaken in thinking that Spray should be able to automatically format the interval class?

If so, then (as the error message appears to suggest) should I be providing a formatter with more explicit information about the fields of Interval? How might this most readily be achieved?

**EDIT**: The answer by @retrospectacus offers some helpful points, but none of them solve the problem. The workaround I adopted was to provide an explicit description of the types and names of the fields:

```
implicit val intervalFormat = jsonFormat[Int, Int,Interval](Interval, "lower", "upper")
```

This works, but I'm leaving the question open, since it's still not clear why this is necessary.

Comment: Is your `implicit val intervalFormat` in scope of where you are getting the error?

Comment: Yes, thanks - presumably it wouldn't compile otherwise.

Comment: Can you post a minimal working example? I can't see how this might happen, given the code you have posted so far. I suspect the problem is in some code you have not included yet.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Common reasons for this error:

- If you have a `case object Interval` (companion) somewhere, then the jsonFormat should be created like `jsonFormat2(Interval.apply)`.
- Adding a type annotation to the format can help: `implicit val intervalFormat: RootJsonFormat[Interval] = ...`
- Your `Interval` class could be confused with another `Interval` class, possibly `org.joda.time.Interval`, either in the jsonFormat creation or in the place of case class creation or serialization - you may add a prefix or fix imports to avoid this.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**: Another reason for this issue which I just encountered, is if you have any `val` declared within the case class, the serializer won't be able to automatically generate a format. E.g.

```
case class Interval(from: Int, to: Int) {
  val size: Int = to - from
}
```

The error will be "java.lang.RuntimeException: Case class Interval declares additional fields".

This can be solved using the `jsonFormat` overload as described above, or the `val` can be simply changed to a `def`.

Comment: "if you have any val declared within the case class, the serializer won't be able to automatically generate a format" <- I hit this because of `val`s in the trait the case classes extended, and changing them to `def`s fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error for a case class defined inside a class. E.g.

```scala
class TestClass {
  case class TestModel(a: String, b: Int, c: Long)

  trait TestJsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
    implicit def testJf: RootJsonFormat[TestModel] = jsonFormat3(TestModel.apply)
  }

// ...

}
```

was producing an error during compilation `java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot automatically determine case class field names and order for 'TestClass$TestModel', please use the 'jsonFormat' overload with explicit field name specification`

The issue was solved once I moved TestModel to TestClass companion object:

```scala
object TestClass {
  case class TestModel(a: String, b: Int, c: Long)

  trait TestJsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
    implicit def testJf: RootJsonFormat[TestModel] = jsonFormat3(TestModel.apply)
  }
}

class TestClass {
  import TestClass._
  // ...
}
```

I hope this will be useful.